# how to write mysql query with multiple fields(having combinations in where clause)

Tags: mysql

[image: please have a look on imgae]

in the above picture i have 6 fields , from them my search can be any combination of 6 fields , it can be only `class` or `class-section` or `class-section-caste`

how can i write a single query which is independent of number of parameters.

is it possible to do with and or in where clause

```
class=Frist or (class=first and section=A) or (class=first and section=A and gender=Male)
```

**is it possible to do so , or is there any better to achieve it.**

**Edit**
please have a look on Query

```
query = currentSession.createQuery("select s.studentAdmissionId as studentAdmissionId, s.adsmissionNum as studentAdmnNum ,s.firstname as studentFirstName , s.lastname as studentLastName , s.adharNum as adharNumber ,"
                        + "  peDe.contactNum as mobileNumber  ,m.className as className ,sec.sectionName as sectionName from StudentDetails s, StudentPresentClassDetails pd, MasterCampusClass m ,"
                        + "MasterCampusSection sec , StudentParentDetails peDe  where s.studentAdmissionId = peDe.studentAdmissionId and (pd.studentAdmissionId = s.studentAdmissionId and pd.classId=m.classId) and (pd.studentAdmissionId = s.studentAdmissionId and pd.presentSectionId = sec.sectionId) and pd.classId = :classId or sec.sectionId .........");
```

Comment: How about other field? (`gender`, `religion`, `address`). Do you mean, if you select `class` then the condition is `class=first`, if you select class and gender then your condition is `class=first and gender=male`?

Comment: yes . is it possible ?

Comment: Just make some if statement, if the condition exist then add to the `where` clause

Comment: if its only  `class=first` other fields will be null

Comment: For such thing you should add condition based on field selected. generate dynamic where clause

Comment: okay thank you @Alpesh Jikadra . is it good way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn thank you for your sample code .

there are some mistakes in the code . i wrote the code with reference  @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn  sample code

here it is

```
 Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
            if (classId != null && !classId.equals("Select")) { 
                sql.append(" AND pd.classId = :classId ");
                params.put("classId", classId); // Or values you want
            } 

            if(sectionId != null && !sectionId.equals("Select"))
            {
                 sql.append(" AND pd.presentSectionId = :presentSectionId ");
                 params.put("presentSectionId", sectionId); // Or values you want
            }


            if(gender != null && !gender.equals("Select"))
            {
                 sql.append(" AND s.gender = :gender "); 
                 params.put("gender", gender); // Or values you want
            }

            if(religion != null && !religion.equals("Select"))
            {
                 sql.append(" AND s.religionId = :religionId "); 
                 params.put("religionId", religion); // Or values you want
            }
            if(casteId != null && !casteId.equals("Select"))
            {
                 sql.append(" AND mcaste.casteId = (select mm.parentId from  MasterCaste mm where mm.casteId= :casteId ) "); 
                 params.put("casteId", Integer.parseInt(casteId)); // Or values you want
            }


            query = currentSession.createQuery(sql.toString());

            System.out.println(sql.toString());  

            for (Entry<String, Object> parameters: params.entrySet()) 
            {

                query.setParameter(parameters.getKey(), parameters.getValue());
            }
```

thanks to every one !

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple if statement to create your query:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE 1 = 1 ");
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
if (classValue!= null && !classValue.isEmpty()) {
    sql.append("AND class = :class ");
    params.add("class", classValue); // Or values you want
}
if (sectionValue!= null && !sectionValue.isEmpty()) {
    sql.append("AND section = :section ");
    params.add("section", sectionValue); // Or values you want
}
...
Query query = session.createQuery(sql.toString());
for (Entry<String, Object> parameters: params) {
    query.setParameter(parameters.getKey(), parameters.getValue());
}
```

Comment: thank you @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn but  i am using hibernate .

Comment: you can easily convert this to your codestyle rightnow. Show me your code used for query if you need my help

Comment: please look at my post i kept Query

Comment: thank you @ Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn  will try and let you know.

Comment: One note: If all of your param values are String you can use `Map<String, String>` instead

Comment: thank you @ Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn it worked for but need to do some changes while iterating map and adding to map , i will post complete answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    testTable
WHERE   IF(
            :filter1 IS NOT NULL,
            col1 = :filter1,
            1 = 1
        )
        AND IF(
            :filter2 IS NOT NULL,
            `col2` = :filter2,
            1 = 1
        )
        AND IF(
            :filter3 IS NOT NULL,
            col3 = :filter3,
            1 = 1
        );
```

And so on. Clean and simple SQL